# Redirecting SideBySide Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, .net-assembly, side-by-side

I'm trying to use SideBySide assemblies in my .Net application. The application structure is set up in a way that all assemblies/dependencies are placed in a linked subdirectory. The configuration file references this directory using "probing privatePath=...". Is it possible to move the manifest file or the specified SideBySide assemblies to the folder as well?

Comment: can you show a full entry from the application manifest for a sample of one of the assemblies in a subdir?

Comment: Also, are these COM based DLLs from some unmanaged language? If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="LinkedSubdirectory"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Here, the  element specifies that the application should look for assemblies in the LinkedSubdirectory relative to the application's base directory. Remember to adjust the configuration values based on your actual subdirectory structure.

Make sure your application is aware of the new assembly location and the updated private path configuration. This involves updating the application configuration file (e.g., app.config or web.config) with the appropriate probing element and privatePath attribute values.

Comment: This part is already in my App.config. I need to configure the location of my SideBySide Assemblies. If the SideBySide Assemblies are located next to the Application file (.exe) in the same folder, everything works fine. But I need to locate the SideBySide Assemblies also in the subdirectory, which isnt working right now.